# Using matplotlib to draw networkx graph with nodes of differing size

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have nodes in a graph "g" that are strings with a "size" attribute. The size attribute is based on the number of times a string occurs in a list "collabList"

```
for a in collabList :
  if a in g :
    try :
      g.node[a]['size'] += 1
    except KeyError :
      pass  
  else :
    g.add_node(a, {'size' : 1})
    g.add_edge(sampleProf, a)
```

For example if the string, "Will J", occurs in collabList 5 times, than...

```
>>>print g.node["Will J"]
{'size' : 5}
```

So now I want to draw the graph in matplotlib so that the size of a node is proportional to the value mapped to size.

nx.draw(g) takes "node_size" as an optional attribute (if it is not entered than default = 300). I want to be able to have "node_size" for each node be equal to the size value * 300.

i.e.

```
g.node["Will J"] = {"size" : 5} --> node_size = 5 * 300
```

Any help/ guidance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Where's your plotting code?

Comment: right now my plotting code is just ``nx.draw_circular(g)``

Answer (score 0):

i iterated through my nodes, pull out the value from the attribute dictionary of each node and appended that value into a list. I then passed that list into node_size and it worked!